# Annotations in `plotly.subplots` break when using custom plot titles

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a weird problem - not sure if it's a bug or I'm missing something.

- When plotting subplots with `Code 1` and assigning custom titles to each subplot - the annotations I try to add later to the bottom plot doe not show fully, but only the last two (`Output Plot 1`).

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from math import exp

fig = make_subplots(2, 1, subplot_titles=['Activation', 'Prediction errors - Model, ALO and RND'])

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-0.1 * x + 5)), x)))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=f'\N{Greek Small Letter Sigma}(x)',
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
fig['layout']['xaxis'].update(title_text='x')

for i in range(4):
    x = np.where(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)==1)[0]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=np.zeros_like(x) + i,
            name=f'Plot {i}',
            mode='markers', 
            marker=dict(
                    symbol='circle-open',
                    color='green',
                    size=5
                ),
            showlegend=True
        ),
        row=2,
        col=1
    )
fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(title_text='active users', range=[0, 10], autorange=True)
fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(title_text='active users', visible=False, autorange=True)
fig['layout'].update(
    annotations=[
    dict(x=0, y=0.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='True activity', font=dict(size=10, color='green')),
    dict(x=0, y=1.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='Model', font=dict(size=10, color='blue')),
    dict(x=0, y=2.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='ALO', font=dict(size=10, color='red')),
    dict(x=0, y=3.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='RND', font=dict(size=10, color='black')),
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

**Output Plot 1**

[image]

On the other hand, if I remove the custom plot labels - everything works as intended, as shown in `Code 2` and output `Image 2`.

**Code 2:**

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from math import exp

fig = make_subplots(2, 1)#, subplot_titles=['Activation', 'Prediction errors - Model, ALO and RND']) # <= note the change here

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-0.1 * x + 5)), x)))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=f'\N{Greek Small Letter Sigma}(x)',
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
fig['layout']['xaxis'].update(title_text='x')

for i in range(4):
    x = np.where(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)==1)[0]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=np.zeros_like(x) + i,
            name=f'Plot {i}',
            mode='markers', 
            marker=dict(
                    symbol='circle-open',
                    color='green',
                    size=5
                ),
            showlegend=True
        ),
        row=2,
        col=1
    )
fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(title_text='active users', range=[0, 10], autorange=True)
fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(title_text='active users', visible=False, autorange=True)
fig['layout'].update(
    annotations=[
    dict(x=0, y=0.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='True activity', font=dict(size=10, color='green')),
    dict(x=0, y=1.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='Model', font=dict(size=10, color='blue')),
    dict(x=0, y=2.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='ALO', font=dict(size=10, color='red')),
    dict(x=0, y=3.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='RND', font=dict(size=10, color='black')),
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

**Output Plot 2**

[image]

Thanks in advance for any elaboration regarding this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is due to the setting of the subtitles, but `add_annotation()` is correct,
The `update(annotations=[]` may have been overwritten by the function to update the annotations that have been set.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from math import exp

fig = make_subplots(2, 1, subplot_titles=('Activation', 'Prediction errors - Model, ALO and RND'))

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 / (1 + exp(-0.1 * x + 5)), x)))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        name=f'\N{Greek Small Letter Sigma}(x)',
        showlegend=True
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
fig['layout']['xaxis'].update(title_text='x')

for i in range(4):
    x = np.where(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)==1)[0]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=np.zeros_like(x) + i,
            name=f'Plot {i}',
            mode='markers', 
            marker=dict(
                    symbol='circle-open',
                    color='green',
                    size=5
                ),
            showlegend=True
        ),
        row=2,
        col=1
    )
fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(title_text='active users', autorange=True)
fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(title_text='active users', visible=True, range=[-1,4])

fig.add_annotation(
    dict(x=0, y=3.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='RND', showarrow=True, font=dict(size=10, color='black'))
)
fig.add_annotation(
    dict(x=0, y=2.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='ALO', showarrow=True, font=dict(size=10, color='red'))
)
fig.add_annotation(
    dict(x=0, y=1.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='Model', showarrow=True, font=dict(size=10, color='Blue'))
)
fig.add_annotation(
    dict(x=0, y=0.125, xref='x2', yref='y2', text='True activity', showarrow=True, font=dict(size=10, color='green'))
)

fig.show()
```

[image]